# Navigation with anchor links does not work

Tags: html, css

Got 3 navigation options. When I click on them, I want my page to scroll to this item. I did like in tutorials. 
       Made an anchor link above and named a section, where to move. 
       But when I clicked on the anchor, my nav went a little bit top and thats all. 
       That happened with every link I clicked. Help!!

```
    Navs:

      <div class="bar" id="about"><a href="#about"><b>About</b></a></div>
      <div class="bar" id="skills"><a href="#skills"><b>Skills</b></a></div>
      <div class="bar" id="contacts"><a href="#contacts"><b>Contacts</b></a></div>

    Sections:

      <h3 class="about_head"><a id="about">Some facts about me</a></h3>
      <h3 class="skills_head"><a id="skills">Langugages and Tools i'm familiar with</a></h3>
      <h3 class="postcard_head"><a id="contacts">Leave your feedback</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove id from all the `div` tags, it will work

```
<div class="bar"><a href="#about"><b>About</b></a></div>
<div class="bar"><a href="#skills"><b>Skills</b></a></div>
<div class="bar"><a href="#contacts"><b>Contacts</b></a></div>

<div class="bar" id="about"><a href="#about"><b>About</b></a></div>
<div class="bar" id="skills"><a href="#skills"><b>Skills</b></a></div>
<div class="bar" id="contacts"><a href="#contacts"><b>Contacts</b></a></div>
```